# Setting up Python on Apache/Windows; IDE question

Tags: python, xampp

I am finally learning Python after putting it off for a long time.
I am setting it up on Apache (XAMPP), which [version of mod_python](http://httpd.apache.org/modules/python-download.cgi#python3210) should I choose?

If I get mod_python-3.3.1.win32-py2.5-Apache2.2.exe, does that mean I have to download Python 2.5 from [here](http://www.python.org/download/)?

*EDIT:* I'll use this primarily for web development. Which IDE should I use? I like Netbeans for Java and PHP, but they don't have Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use mod_python - it is now officially [dead](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html). You should use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) instead. There are [instructions for installing it on Windows](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows).

Answer (score 1):

For an IDE that also plays well with web development, download [Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/)
which is built upon eclipse and then get the pydev extension for it.

And you will need the python 2.5 version as you suspect.

Comment: Wow, mod_python's last version was released more than 3 years ago. Is there another way for me to use a newer version of the interpreter in a web server?

Comment: Yes, mod_python is dead. See my answer.